# Do I need to sort an array to find its median?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I need to create a code where if i for example call `func([4, 8, 2, 4, 5])` the method should return the object `{max: 8, mean: 4.6, median: 4, min: 2, range: 6}`.

Where should I start? Do I need a code for sorting the numbers or is there a code so the computer can find the median without the numbers being sorted first?

Comment: Please share your effort...

Comment: Send us what you have tried so far.

Comment: There's no need to sort anything to derive these statistics; you just loop over those numbers and update your statistics as you progress…

Comment: @deceze: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median

Answer (score 2):

You can find a median without sorting the numbers, but that's hard if you want to do that efficiently (for every element count the number of elements less and equal to it, do that till you find element that has correct median count, that means it's in the middle, if number of elements is even then it's even more problematic), plus you can also use sorting for other statistics (max, min etc.) so why not just sort? You can sort array with `sort()` method.